# Windows 8 scroll lag

Tags: windows, windows-8, touchpad, modern-ui

Don't have an issue with the desktop experience, but when it comes to the apps, scrolling in some of them is impossible to use correctly.  Very laggy and jumpy, which is surprising because my computer has relatively high specs, only a year old.

Scrolling using the manual scroll bar has no lag whatsoever it's simply whenever I use my touchpad.

Maybe it's a touchpad issue? or more likely windows 8 as it seems fine in desktop view for scrolling?

Any ideas where the problem may lie?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns it was due to a scrolling program I was using to invert the scrolling called 'wizmouse'.

This created the lag, if you wish to invert the scrolling this can be done manually through the registry with no 3rd party apps.

Comment: could you please describe the registry changes

Comment: @Khaleel Search for flipflopwheel and set the value to 1 instead of 0. essentially just reverses the scroll and that is all.

Answer (score 1):

Its likely your Touchpad driver that's causing the lag. A lot of Dell laptops have reported this issue. I'm guessing yours could be related (plz correct me otherwise). Try installing a 3rd party drivers such as [synaptics](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/windows8&ei=zafGUIOPAsiQ2AXlpICwAw&usg=AFQjCNHQ830_PQeXMF6E0lsEMUg_FEcQ8w&sig2=Tz_SKMV-cZg1G_x8qP4PLw)